Azure-pipelines : if condition in each loop not working
Consider below code :
parameters:
  - name: containerRegistry
    displayName: Azure Container Registry Service Connection
    type: string
    default: 'acr-amaest'
    values:
      - acr-amaest

  - name: deploymentSteps
    type: stepList
    default:
      - script: echo "Add your deployment steps to your template"
        displayName: Empty deployment step

  - name: branchMapping
    type: object
    default:
      develop: build
      staging: staging
      main: release

variables:
  - name: environment
    ${{ each branch in parameters.branchMapping }}:
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ branch.Key }}') }}:
        value: ${{ branch.Value }}

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName:  Test
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
        # Printing empty string
        - bash: |
            echo ${{ variables['environment'] }}
        # Works, prints everything
        - ${{ each branch in parameters.branchMapping }}:
          - bash: echo '${{ branch.Key }} -> ${{ branch.Value }} against ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}'
        # Prints nothing    
        - ${{ each branch in parameters.branchMapping }}:
           - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], '/${{ branch.Key }}') }}:
             - bash: echo "Coucou ${{ branch.Key }}"

Could you please help ?
EDIT
Final answer is :
variables:
  - name: environment
    ${{ each branch in parameters.branchMapping }}:
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], format('refs/heads/{0}', branch.Key)) }}:
        value: ${{ branch.Value }}


Can you describe in very simple terms what you're trying to achieve?

Simply: to detect which environment to use depending on branch name at compile time. Above code is a template each caller can override by giving a different mapping if needed

In order to set a variable named environment based on the selected branch you can do the following:
parameters:
  # other parameters here

  - name: branchMapping
    type: object
    default:
      develop: build_environment
      staging: staging_environment
      main: release_environment

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: sourceBranch
    value: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

  - name: environment
    ${{ each branch in parameters.branchMapping }}:
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], branch.Key) }}:
        value: ${{ branch.Value }}

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName:  Test
  jobs:
    - job: printVariables
      displayName: 'Print variables'
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - bash: |
            echo "sourceBranch: ${{ variables.sourceBranch }}"
            echo "environment: ${{ variables.environment }}"
          displayName: 'Print variables'
        - bash: |
            echo "sourceBranch: $(sourceBranch)"
            echo "environment: $(environment)"
          displayName: 'Print variables using macro syntax'

Running the pipeline from the staging branch:


Why does it works with SourceBranchName and not SourceBranch? I’m not of using names because some may bypass main by pushing « my/main » which will work also. Or am I wrong ?

I decided to use Build.SourceBranchName to keep the code slightly simpler. Mine is just an example, just adapt it to your specific use case.

Your code just confirms that it doesn't works when switching to SourceBranch. Just copied your code, switched to the variable I wanted to use and I observe the same result as my initial post while yours is working ...

@ArnaudF. is not just a matter of copying the code and changing the variable - you obviously need to change the condition as well.

I got the point, I've written ${{ branch.Key }} in the ${{ if ... }} while I should have write branch.Key combined with format directly, now it works. Thanks for everything :)

Glad that it's working fine now :-)

@ArnaudF. you deserve an upvote for finding the fix on your own, using Build.SourceBranch :-)
